# Detect coordinates within a shape

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, animate-cc

Theres 2 parts to my problem and they are related. I have a weird shape on my interface illustrated below, I am trying to randomly spawn MovieClips within its' boundaries but I am having some trouble finding a good way to do it.[image: WeirdShape]

**Question 1**: I can run an If condition to check with bitMapData.hitTest to see if the MovieClip has randomly spawn within this shape, if it doesn't simply retry with a new set of random coordinates. However, is there a better way? Like a way to only take into account coordinates within the shape? There will be plenty of MC spawned at one go so I am hoping to lessen the load, or at least find an efficient way to do this calculation.

**Question 2**: The MovieClips spawned within this shape will eventually have collision detection mechanics that will repel itself when interacted with. *Is there a way to contain them within this shape via some kind of boundary detection?*

If it was a square, we could easily have contained them with a quick check on all 4 edges, but not with this shape. Currently I am thinking of using bitMapData.hitTest again to detect for out-of-bounds after being repelled, but how do I know which Point() is the nearest 'edge' of this shape to return the MC to?

Comment: I'm not a game dev who deals with this stuff really,  but I think your proposed solution of checking bitmap data hit is probably going to have to be the way to go (though I'm interested to see if someone has a more performant solution for you).

Comment: As for snapping, that's even more interesting and I'm curious what kind of answers you may get.   One option (that isn't going to be super accurate) would be to check the destination position before setting it, and if it moves it out of bounds, leave it in it's current position.   Are you going to implement a physics engine to do the heavy lifting?

Comment: I advice to employ a ready solution like Box2D (there's AS3 library) to set up collisions and stuff. Collision physics is an advanced subject, it is not unlikely for you to spend **A LOT** of time and effort on your own solution and never get any close to what an existing solution provides. Well, unless you have a good understanding of it or your ultimate goal **is** your own 2D-physics engine.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies, I didn't know about Box2D so that's is definitely going to be my next step for qns2. Is Box2D able to do boundary detection for that weird shape? I am concerned about having to contain the movieclips within that shape. One thing I didn't specify on the topic was that the objects itself does not need to have collision mechanics with each other, but only repel from an input value I will receive from my interface. An eg. if the input is Point(30,30), I would need to repel the MovieClips away from 30,30 by a certain distance. There will be multiple inputs as well.

Answer (score 1):

**For question 1**: I'm going to go on an assumption that you have some geometry data about the shape.

One method you can use to check if a point is within a shape is to take that point, then draw a line from that point to infinity (the edge of the screen) in one direction. Then count how many times that line intersects an edge of the shape. If it's odd, the point is within the shape (or on the edge) and if it's even, than that point is outside of the shape.

First link in google: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/

Or can also try a more simple method (at the cost of doing more work): if the above shape is generated with all squares and rectangles and you know the point and size of all of those: can just do a check for the point vs all the squares and rectangles that make up the shape.

**For question 2**: As Organis mentioned, I'd go with a library like Box2D to do this. You'll most likely spend tons of time (that you may not want to) if you try to implement this alone.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I checked the link you provided for qns1 and it's a pretty smart solution. It might be slower than bitMapData.hitTest but I can use it for qns2 boundary detection. However, as I have yet to try Box2D, I am not sure if there is an inbuilt capability to detect boundaries of shapes like this. Can you shed some light? Else I will update again when I've tried Box2D.

Comment: My instinct tells me it should be faster then any pixel based method, but I could be wrong (line intersection tests can be done with just math). One way to know for sure is to implement both and measure the results. You may find the easier to implement method (whatever one) is slow, but acceptable for your use case. It's been quite sometime since I've touched Box2D that I can't say for certain though convex shapes shouldn't be an issue. You may have to adapt your shape generation code to fit in Box2D's method of working. Check Box2D's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue is how much cpu or gpu the code uses. You're trying to avoid using any collision detection. Collision detection is having code do calculations to determine the edges of an object. It should be the last option.

Most of the time you know there's no need for collision detection. You know where everything is and how big it is. Everything has a centerpoint and comparing simple number coordinates is the lightweight way to check if there's a need to check further.

When things get near each other, you only need to do a collision detection on the immediate area around an object. See how your shape fits in a box that is easy to check for collisions? That box should get a collision check before the actual jagged shape inside it.

[image]

Yes that collision detection box has to be drawn or mapped but it's done when the object is defined, not when the game is playing. If you are using sprite sheets, keep an xml of the boxes or circles around the shapes.